# Akka 2.6 how to read `Dead Letters` in Akka Typed?

Tags: akka, actor, dead-letter, akka-typed, actorsystem

I have read this doc **https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#dead-letters**, which says:

> An actor can subscribe to class akka.actor.DeadLetter on the event stream, see Event Stream for how to do that.

in the Event Stream doc: **https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/event-bus.html#event-stream**, sample code seems about classic Akka, and package is `akka.actor.ActorSystem` not `akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem`:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;

final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("DeadLetters");
final ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(Props.create(DeadLetterActor.class));
system.getEventStream().subscribe(actor, DeadLetter.class);
```

but in Akka Typed, there is no method named `subscribe()` in`akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem.eventStream()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After creating a typed ActorSystem and a typed Actor that handles the message type DeadLetter, you should be able to subscribe to the EventStream like shown below.

```
import akka.actor.typed.eventstream.EventStream;

system.eventStream().tell(new EventStream.Subscribe(DeadLetter.class, actor));
```